# How to make Ubuntu beep (a few seconds) before suspend?

Tags: suspend, power-management

I want the beep to alert me so that sometimes I can nudge the mouse a bit just to keep the system running.  (I've set the inactivity time to be very short).

How can this be done?

I'm using Lubuntu 16.04 to be exact.

Answer (score 4):

First install `beep` package:

```
sudo apt install beep
```

Then load `pcspkr` module, by default pc speaker is not enable (module is not loaded):

```
sudo modprobe pcspkr
```

Now install `xprintidle`, it's a utility to print user's idle time.

Finally we need a command to check if idle time was bigger than of X, runs beep:

```
if [ `xprintidle` -ge 3000 ]; then beep; fi
```

- 3000 means 3 second, e.g: if your system goes to sleep after 10 Minutes you should use something around "540000" (9 Min) so it is able to make a alert 1 Min before system goes to sleep.

After all create a line in `/etc/crontab` to run this command every minute:

```
* * * * *   username   if [ `xprintidle` -ge 540000 ]; then beep; fi
```