# Disable suspend while running VLC

Tags: command-line, suspend, vlc

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and I have a few little bash aliases set up like this:

`alias radio='cvlc http://internet/radio/stream.pls -q'`

so I can just quickly fire up some music in Bash. Is there a command I can add to disable suspend while VLC is running and enable it again when I exit VLC? I know I can change the power settings but I'd rather not do that every time I want to play some Internet radio. What's a better general solution?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer to the question: [How to make Ubuntu beep (a few seconds) before suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926668/how-to-make-ubuntu-beep-a-few-seconds-before-suspend/926674#926674) a few days ago, I'm going to use the same concept for your situation.

Install `xdotool` package:

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Create a script, save it somewhere you like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
sleep 2
while [ `pgrep -x vlc` ]
do
 xdotool key shift 
 sleep 60;
done
```

Change you alias to:

```
alias radio='bash ~/path/myscript.sh & cvlc http://internet/radio/stream.pls -q'
```

Now this script makes some fake activities every minute while `vlc` is running so your computer is not going to sleep.